# Does a Mobx @observer Component trigger `render` or `forceUpdate`?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, mobx

Does a `Mobx` `@observer` component trigger `render` or `forceUpdate` on that component when the observable updates? What lifecycle methods are triggered when it does? Is there a difference between `render` and `forceUpdate`?

How children are left untouched even if they are in the render method? Is `React` or `Mobx` responsible for detecting when props are passed into a child and it needs to be re-rendered?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

For class based components, Mobx does essentially use force update (as part of its reaction to properties that were observed in the first render). Functional components behave somewhat differently, and newer versions of Mobx use react hooks when possible.

Child components will re-render if their props change (like [react pure components](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactpurecomponent)). Also, if a child component has observable props or children that are dereferenced in a parent component, that can cause that component to be re-rendered as well, on change.